# How can I replace only the first 2 matches per line, using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to parse a list of filenames to a CSV file by converting the first 2 `-` characters per line into a `|`. The problem is that the filenames themselves also contain the character I'm searching for.

My raw data looks something like this:

```
12055371-1-Florence - BW Letter of Intent HB Comments 9-4-14-2.DOCX
12057668-2-EB-DUE-M- SBuxbaum FHA Benefit Plans-2.DOCX
12058210-1-Redline Letter of Intent-2.PDF
12058029-3-Florence Hospital--Order Establishing Bid Procedures-HB 9-23-14-2.DOCX 
12058020-10-Florence - BW Letter of Intent 10,10,14 Revisions-2.DOCX
```

Using Notepadd++ to replace on the fly, but I'm not sure what regex will work to identify and replace these items.

Comment: **[alternative](https://regex101.com/r/zB6tX4/1)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't match `-`, match the beginning of the lines up to the second `-` :

```
match ^(.*?)-(.*?)-
replace by \1|\2|
```

Explanation :

- `^` matches the beginning of the line (0-width match).
- `(.*?)` matches any character in a non-greedy way : if the next token of the regex can match, it will let it do so. The result is grouped so it can be referenced later.
- `\1` and `\2` are back-references and  refers to the two `(.*?)` groups.

Note : for efficiency you could replace the non-greedy matches by the negated class `[^\-]`, which means every character but `-`, the `-` being escaped because it's a special character in this context. The groups would then become `([^\-]*)`. Of course it really does not matter if it's a one-time operation.